# Moving from JDK 1.7 to JDK 1.8 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, java-8

I am on UBUNTU. JDK version currently installed is:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

the configuration being installed is:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java 
(providing /usr/bin/java):     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

I downloaded the latest tar.gz archive of JDK 1.8.

How can I easily install JDK 1.8 from tar.gz overriding/uninstalling the JDK 1.7 currently installed? Or even without explicitly use the tar.gz.

Comment: personally, I just download `tar.gz`, and unzip it to local directory (under ~).

Comment: http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/#

Answer (score 76):

This is what I do on debian - I suspect it should work on ubuntu (amend the version as required + adapt the folder where you want to copy the JDK files as you wish, I'm using `/opt/jdk`):

```
wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u71-b15/jdk-8u71-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /opt/jdk
sudo tar -zxf jdk-8u71-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk/
rm jdk-8u71-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Then update-alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/java 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/javac 1
```

Select the number corresponding to the `/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/java` when running the following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Finally, verify that the correct version is selected:

```
java -version
javac -version
```

Comment: Newer jdk, 8u60, found at: `http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u60-b27/jdk-8u60-linux-x64.tar.gz` Note that this will not work without the cookie set, so use `wget` as in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it was already installed but just not the default. 
`sudo update-alternatives --config javac` was then enough.

Comment: Worked for me using jdk 8u65. Thanks!

Comment: How do you remove the older versions safely after install the newer version?

Comment: Java 9 is gonna release shortly . just for extra information though : )

Comment: Update: the url gives a 404. Still, one could just download `tar` file and follow the rest of the instructions.

Answer (score 51):

Just use these command lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

If needed, you can also follow this [Ubuntu tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-installing-oracle-java7-on-ubuntu-linux/).

Comment: The java 8 installer seems to require interaction to agree to their TOS, even with `apt-get install -y`... Is there any way to force it to agree from the command line so that this can be automated, e.g. in Vagrant?

Comment: When your system is behind a proxy, use 'sudo -E' to preserve environment, and make sure appropriate proxy env's are configured.

Comment: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 41):

Add the repository and update apt-get:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Java8 and set it as default:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Check version:

```
java -version
```

Comment: easiest one so far, thanx!

Comment: Installed successfully.

Answer (score 19):

You can easily install 1.8 via PPA. Which can be done by:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Then check the running version:

```
$ java -version
```

If you must do it manually there's already an answer for that on AskUbuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: Can you tell me specifically which command failed? The first one?

Comment: The second one... lots of messages like these: W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP:...

Comment: Are you using an LTS release of Ubuntu?

Comment: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 13.10
Release: 13.10
Codename: saucy

Comment: you think I should upgrade this Ubuntu to 14.04 LTS?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is end-of-live and has been since July of 2014. Maybe they left the packages on the server for a while, but they are gone now. The best thing to do is installing a supported release of Ubuntu. Or if you don't want to upgrade you'll need to attempt a manual installation like I liked in the original answer.

Comment: I solved with this:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre

Comment: This does not differ from the answer above in any way.

Comment: Idk if you've noticed but I was the first to answer -_-' well besides Kapcash below who beat me by two minutes.

Answer (score 10):

You can do the following to install java 8 on your machine. First get the link of `tar` that you want to install. You can do this by:

> 1. go to java downloads [page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and find the appropriate download.
> 2. Accept the license agreement and download it.
> 3. In the download page in your browser right click and `copy link address`.

Then in your terminal:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u74-b02/jdk-8u74-linux-x64.tar.gz\?AuthParam\=1458001079_a6c78c74b34d63befd53037da604746c
$ tar xzf jdk-8u74-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1458001079_a6c78c74b34d63befd53037da604746c
$ sudo mv jdk1.8.0_74 /opt
$ cd /opt/jdk1.8.0_74/
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java 2
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java // select version
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /opt/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/jar 2
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/javac 2
$ sudo update-alternatives --set jar /opt/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/jar
$ sudo update-alternatives --set javac /opt/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/javac
$ java -version // you should have the updated java
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers for this question can not helped me in 2020.

This notification from download [site](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html) of Oracle may be the reason:

> Important Oracle JDK License Update
>
> The Oracle JDK License has changed for releases starting April 16, 2019.

I try to google a little bit and those tutorials below helped me a lot.

1. [Remove completely the previous version of JVM installed on your
   PC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ioXMu8R45A).

   ```sh
   sudo update-alternatives --remove-all java
   sudo update-alternatives --remove-all javac
   sudo update-alternatives --remove-all javaws

   # /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0 is the path you installed the previous version of JVM on your PC
   sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
   ```

   Check to see whether java is uninstalled or not

   ```sh
   java -version
   ```
2. [Install Java 8
   JDK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zp10aJqj51M).

   - Download Java 8 from Oracle's [website](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html). The version being used is `1.8.0_251`. Pay attention to this value, you may need it to edit commands in this answer when Java 8 is upgraded to another version.
   - Extract the compressed file to the place where you want to install.

   ```
   cd /usr/lib/jvm
   sudo tar xzf ~/Downloads/jdk-8u251-linux-x64.tar.gz
   ```

   - Edit environment file

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/environment
   ```

   - Edit the PATH's value by appending the string below to the current value

   ```
   :/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/bin
   ```

   - Append those strings to the environment file

   ```
   J2SDKDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251"
   J2REDIR="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251/jre"
   JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251"
   ```

   - Complete the installation by running commands below

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251/bin/java" 0
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251/bin/javac" 0
   sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251/bin/java
   sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251/bin/javac

   update-alternatives --list java
   update-alternatives --list javac
   ```