# Install Java 8 in debian Jessie

Tags: java, linux, jvm, debian

I've tried to install Java 8 into a ARM embedded linux in several ways but none of them worked:

First: 
http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

(from the repositories of webupd8)

> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
>   Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages' in Release
>   file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-armel/Packages
>   404  Not Found
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

It seems that this repo does not have the source for my architecture:

> Architectures: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el

And i need armel ( at least this is working for java 7 )

I also tried this way:
http://www.rpiblog.com/2014/03/installing-oracle-jdk-8-on-raspberry-pi.html

Downloading the jdk from Oracle and then following the instructions.

But i cannot execute the file :

> root@arietta:~# java -version
>   -bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

and neither:

> root@arietta:~# /opt/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/java -version
>   -bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

While **the file exists and has the correct permissions**... i'm going crazy..

Any idea or alternative method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30184954/829571

Comment: i also tried this (the link there is for linux 64 bits, i'm getting another version), still not working, is the same as the second alternative i posted

Comment: What does `update-alternatives --display java` show? Is your debian 32 or 64 bit? Which version of java did you download (32 vs 64)? This may be relevant to you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/207552

Comment: `update-alternatives --display java` displays the 2 diferent version paths that  i hve, but then when i select the 1.8 is not working, i get this message. I'm using ARM, i already tried this from askubuntu before and it's also not working..  :S

Answer (score 44, accepted):

At the end i solved it adding jessie backports to the sources.list:

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main >> /etc/apt/sources.list

apt-get update && apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk

update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: I get an error: "**-bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied**"

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky You need to run the commands as root or using `sudo`

Comment: i have added above to /etc/apt/sources.list, but still get 404 not found

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342403/openjdk-8-jre-headless-depends-ca-certificates-java-but-it-is-not-going-to-be  for recent issue with new certificates and fix.

Comment: How did you manage to get the GPG key imported with these commands?

Answer (score 9):

I ran the following commands from the webupd8 team and it worked for me: 
http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

```
su -
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
exit
```

Comment: works fine for me inside a docker container (library/node)

Answer (score 1):

Same as @user2528085, you just need to add Debian backports to your sourcelist file.

Follow this instruction on Debian official site
https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

Run these commands in shell:

```
echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
```

Nothing difficult