# RIght JVM folder for IDE

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, netbeans, java-7

Typing **cd /usr/lib/jvm** from shell I see the following:

```
default-java        java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386  java-6-openjdk-common
java-1.5.0-gcj-4.6  java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386  java-6-openjdk-i386
java-1.6.0-openjdk  java-6-openjdk       java-7-openjdk-i386
```

can someone explain what's the difference between *java-1.x..* and *java-x-openjdk* folders?

More specifically, when I want to set default jdk in Netbeans or Eclipse, which folders should I use out of those two types?

Comment: The difference is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-open-jdk-and-garbage-collection

Comment: @Johan a while ago you asked about installing Java 1.8 on Ubuntu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177455/moving-from-jdk-1-7-to-jdk-1-8-on-ubuntu You should set up that as your default JVM to use. All the JVMs in your question are now out EOL.

Answer (score 1):

Although I cannot tell for sure, but I suspect that all the `java-6-*` are soft links to `java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386`. Likewise, all the `java-7-*` are soft links to `java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386`.

If you want to tell for sure, do `ls -l` so you can see the details of the files, including what they are links to.

If you still need Java 5, 6 and 7 (even though they are [EOL](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml)) then you can add any of the paths (linked or not) to Eclipse.

As for which should be your default, install Java 8 and set that up as the default. The best way on Ubuntu is probably [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30177616/2796832) (see [docs](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```