# cordova-cli : Depends: nodejs-legacy but it is not going to be installed

Tags: java, node.js, cordova, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I am working for Ionic,
I get install all require dependencies, now I need to upgrade Java version by [using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177455/moving-from-jdk-1-7-to-jdk-1-8-on-ubuntu):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

I also go through this link to install Java-
https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04

when I run last command, I get error like-
    $ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cordova-cli : Depends: nodejs-legacy but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also try with:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

but won't work for me.
Need help !!